# How can I append <DIV> tag which cames from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, append

I am new for the Ajax and I am working on the application which provide employee salary as per user input value.

Now, My question is I am trying to get the data from Ajax in that I wish to display that portion at particular place on my main page

Let me explain you what I am actually asking for, please have a look:

```
<div id=main>
     <div id=1st>
     </div>

     <div id=2nd>
     </div>
</div>
<div>
     <div id=display_result>
     </div>
</div>
```

above is the sample and I am passing data of id=2nd div & id=display_result div tags which belongs from two different class of CSS and as their own separate position.

Here is the actual code in which I am facing the problem.

```
    <div id="find_max_div" class="table-div select-table" style="width:95% !important;">
        <div style="text-align:right;">
            <img width="30px" src="MaxVal_image/close.png" style="margin-right:20px;" class="mousepointer" title="close" name="close1" id="close1">
        </div>
        <div style="display:flex;">
            <div class="position-div-left row_th">
                <div class="position-left"> Enter position: </div>
                <div class="position-right">
                    <input type="text" size="40" name="position" id="position" placeholder="Enter position" class="textbox">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="position-div-right row_th" id="same_emp_sal_list-div">
                <div class="position-left"> Select Employee: </div>
                <div class="position-right">
                    <select name="same_sal_emp_list" id="same_sal_emp_list" class="textbox">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="max_result_table" style="margin-top:12px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am passing the data from:

```
        <div class="position-div-left row_th">
            <div class="position-left"> Enter position: </div>
            <div class="position-right">
                <input type="text" size="40" name="position" id="position" placeholder="Enter position" class="textbox">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please show your minimal (even broken) attempt(s), and explain the problem you're trying to solve, where are you stuck? What help do you need?

Comment: above is the sample code.

Comment: David, I placed the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :-

```
<div class="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'YOUR PHP page url',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I have got the data... but I wish to place that data at proper position which I couldn't able to do that so....

Comment: you can place those data in div, as I shown here. And that div can be anywhere on your page